# Draw images on a 2d t-sne scatter plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn

The following figure is a t-sne scatter plot of a batch of numpy image arrays, which is of shape (2500,64,64,1). How do I replace each blue dot on the figure with the its own original image?

I used the following code to draw the figure:

```
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

tsne = TSNE(n_components=2).fit_transform(images)
# plot the result
vis_x = tsne[:, 0]
vis_y = tsne[:, 1]

plt.figure(figsize = (160,120))
plt.scatter(vis_x, vis_y)
plt.show()
```

[image: t-sne scatter plot of the images arrays]

Comment: No, it doesn't. My data type is np.array, but the link has images of .jpg data type, they have different specs.

Comment: @jabberwoo `plt.imshow` accepts a 2D array, so that the code in the linked question should work fine.